# jQuery Ajax não funciona no IE8 e IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

Estou usando o Internet Explorer 9 para testes e as requisições ajax não funcionam (em todos os outros navegadores elas funcionam).

Tenho esse código:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://cep.correiocontrol.com.br/60441145.json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) { 
        alert('sucess');
    },
    error: function (request, status, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    } 
});
```

O IE retorna "NO TRANSPORT". Pesquisei em fóruns e vi que a solução era colocar, acima do script:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```

Adicionei mas no IE agora retorna "OBJECT ERROR". Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está tentando usar CORS, que é um método para permitir acesso a outro domínio via Ajax. O IE só passou a suportar isso da maneira padrão a partir da versão 10, e o jQuery não dá suporte a CORS para IE8 e IE9. Você pode usar um plugin para ativar esse suporte, como [isto aqui](https://github.com/jaubourg/ajaxHooks/blob/master/src/xdr.js).

**Fonte:** [Resposta em inglês no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10232313).